# Databrick Azure broadcast variables not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

So I am trying to create a extremely simple spark notebook using Azure Databricks and would like to make use of a simple RDD map call.

This is just for messing around, so the example  is a bit contrived, but I can not get a value to work in the RDD map call unless it is a static constant value

I have tried using a **broadcast variable**

Here is a simple example using an int which I broadcast and then try and use in the RDD map

```
val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

import sqlContext.implicits._
val multiplier = 3
val multiplierBroadcast = sparkContext.broadcast(multiplier)
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val dataRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val mappedRdd = dataRdd.map(x => multiplierBroadcast.value)
val df = mappedRdd.toDF
df.show()
```

Here is another example where I use simple serializable singleton object with an int field which I broadcast and then try and use in the RDD map

```
val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

import sqlContext.implicits._
val multiplier = 3
object Foo extends Serializable { val theMultiplier: Int = multiplier}
val fooBroadcast = sparkContext.broadcast(Foo)
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val dataRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val mappedRdd = dataRdd.map(x => fooBroadcast.value.theMultiplier)
val df = mappedRdd.toDF
df.show()
```

And finally a `List[int]` with a single element which I broadcast and then try and use in the RDD map

```
val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

import sqlContext.implicits._
val multiplier = 3
val listBroadcast = sparkContext.broadcast(List(multiplier))
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val dataRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val mappedRdd = dataRdd.map(x => listBroadcast.value.head)
val df = mappedRdd.toDF
df.show()
```

However ALL the examples above fail with this error. Which as you can see is pointing towards an issue with the RDD map value not being serializable. I can not see the issue, and int value should be serializable using all the above examples I think

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2375)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:378)
```

If I however make the value in the RDD map a regular int value like this

```
val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext

import sqlContext.implicits._
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val dataRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val mappedRdd = dataRdd.map(x => 6)
val df = mappedRdd.toDF
df.show()
```

Everything is working fine and I see my simple DataFrame shown as expected

[image]

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: In all recent versions of Spark, the `Task not serializable` error should be accompanied by more detailed debugging output explaining what, specifically, was not serializable. Can you post some of that here? My hunch is that closure over-capture is occurring and having the complete debug information will help to narrow that down.

Comment: @Josh just out of office today but I'll post that up tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was that you should not capture the Spark content in a val and then use that for the broadcast. So this is working code

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val multiplier = 3
val multiplierBroadcast = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(multiplier)
val data = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val dataRdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val mappedRdd = dataRdd.map(x => multiplierBroadcast.value)
val df = mappedRdd.toDF
df.show()
```

Thanks to @nadim Bahadoor for this answer

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I would assume that you are on Spark 2+. Perhaps, there is no need to drop down to the RDD level and, instead, work with DataFrames.

The code below shows how to join two DataFrames and explicitly **broadcast** the first one.

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val dataDF = data.toDF("id")

val largeDataDF = Seq((0, "Apple"), (1, "Pear"), (2, "Banana")).toDF("id", "value")
val df = largeDataDF.join(broadcast(dataDF), Seq("id"))

df.show()
```

Typically, small DataFrames are perfect candidates for broadcasting as an optimization whereby they are sent to all executors. **spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold** is a configuration which limits the size of DataFrames eligible for broadcast. Additional details can be found on the [Spark official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

Note also that with DataFrames, you have access to a handy **explain** method. With it, you can see the physical plan and it can be useful for debugging.

Running explain() on our example would confirm that Spark is doing a **BroadcastHashJoin** optimization.

```
df.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*Project [id#11, value#12]
+- *BroadcastHashJoin [id#11], [id#3], Inner, BuildRight
:- LocalTableScan [id#11, value#12]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as bigint)))
+- LocalTableScan [id#3]
```

If you need additional help with DataFrames, I provide an extensive list of examples at http://allaboutscala.com/big-data/spark/

Comment: There is a re-scoping of SparkContext in your code `val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext`. Note that SparkCotext is not serializable. Try accessing the `spark.sparkContext` directly within the Azure notebook.

Comment: that was it, I did not know the closure would capture the spark context